# Is referencing 'this' faster than the context object?

Tags: javascript

I'm rewriting a class constructor for a canvas renderer to be just be a single class(figured i won't need more than one canvas for this project). Is referencing the class by 'this' faster than referencing it's name in it's functions? I know referencing the closure context is faster than the global context, but was curious wether this exists as a global or part of the context.

Here's my class for reference:

```
canvasObj = { //canvas initialiser

    init: function(){
        this.el=document.getElement;
        this.c=this.el.getContext('2d');
        this.objs=[];
        this.resetSize();
        this.bAnim=false;
        console.log("canvas initialised");
    },

    clear: function(c){ //fills whole canvas with opaque grey, faster than clearRect()
        if(!c)this.c.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
        this.c.fillRect(0, 0, this.el.width, this.el.height);
    },

    resetSize: function(){ //resizes  the canvas to window size
        this.el.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
        this.el.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
        this.el.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.el.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.w=window.innerWidth;
        this.h=window.innerHeight;
        this.o=this.w/this.h;
        console.log("size changed");
    },

    update: function(t){ //runs all stored draw functions
        var i = this.objs.length, selfRef = this, ts = Date.now();
        while(i--){
            this.objs[i](ts-this.ts);
        }
        this.ts=ts;
        if(this.bAnim===true)
            requestAnimationFrame(function(t){selfRef.update(t);});
    },

    addDraw: function(fn){ //adds new draw function to stack
        this.objs.unshift(fn);
    },

    startAnim: function(){ //starts drawing loop
        var selfRef = this;
        this.ts=Date.now();
        this.bAnim=true;
        requestAnimationFrame(function(t){selfRef.update(t);});
    },

    stopAnim: function(){ //stops drawing loop
        this.bAnim=false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Use jsPerf and see which is faster.

Comment: `I know referencing the closure context is faster than the global context`. A function's `this` is one parameter of an execution context, it has nothing to do with closures. It's only ever resolved in the current execution context and never on the scope chain.

Comment: @RobG When I mentioned closure context I was more referring to local variables within a function closure, not 'this'. So as I understand you 'this' is always part of the top-level context not simply a reassigned global attribute?

Comment: @Barmar I know I can use jsPerf, but I was interested if anyone knew the why rather than the what.

Comment: `this` isn't a real variable -- I'll bet the compiler generates special code to access the context object without going through the scope chain.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I figured... I guess theoretically such a special case should be faster